# Multi-host Docker compose application on Swarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I've a simple compose file, where I've three services A, B and C. Both A and B depends on C (i.e. have `links` to C). Here a simplified excerpt from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
kafka:
  image: spotify/kafka
  environment:
    ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    - "9092:9092"
ServiceA:
  image: elsoufy/myimage
  command: ./mycommand -role producer -queue kafka:9092
  ports:
    - "8080"
ServiceB:
  image: elsoufy/myimage
  command: ./mycommand -role consumer -queue kafka:9092
```

I've setup a Docker swarm on AWS and enabled overlay networking through consul key-store. I've been struggling for a while to get this working properly (I had to manually upgrade the kernel of the machines to [linux 3.16](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay.md)).

I'm using Docker 1.9

```
Client:
 Version:      1.9.0
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   76d6bc9
 Built:        Tue Nov  3 19:20:09 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.0
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   76d6bc9
 Built:        Tue Nov  3 19:20:09 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

I can successfully launch the compose up with `docker-compose up -d`, but `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` crashes after many attempt to connect to `kafka` as they cannot find it. When I try to use explicit `links` and enable overlay for this app [I get an error](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/project.py#l398-l400):

```
docker-compose --x-networking --x-network-driver=overlay up

links, which are not compatible with Docker networking and will be ignored. Future versions of Docker will not support links - you should remove them for forwards-compatibility.
```

It looks like I cannot use `links` when I want to enable multi-host!! But then how I can run a compose application where I've dependencies between containers and scale the containers on a docker swarm?

Comment: The new networking feature in docker 1.9 uses IP host discovery on a shared network as a replacement for links. See the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785804/docker-networking-on-single-host-with-compose/33791395#33791395

Comment: This message is just a warning (not an error). I think it should have a `Warning` prefix on the message, right? It was just cut off in the copy/paste.

Comment: @dnephin I don't have the full message, I've posted this thread a day after seeing the issue.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor thanks for the link, it looks like I have run my containers manually, then what compose is for?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor when I try the tomcat example, the service discovery works, fine but when I try with a zookeeper (run with docker-compose.yml) and kafka (run manually) the discovery does not work.

Comment: Are they using the same network?  We'll need more information to be able to answer the question.

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of the code not working. I would always recommend using docker compose. Makes orchestrating multiple containers a lot easier.

Comment: I added an excerpt of the `docker-compose.yml` file and updated the questions text, sorry I should do that at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need explicit links anymore. Network should link all containers on the same user defined network.  Compose creates a default network for you , based on the project name.

Answer (score 0):

To express dependency between containers or services you can use the configuration option `depends_on` in the `docker-compose.yml` file, but `version 2` file format.

So your docker-compose.yml file should look similar like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    kafka:
      image: spotify/kafka
      environment:
        ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
        - "9092:9092"

    ServiceA:
      image: elsoufy/myimage
      command: ./mycommand -role producer -queue kafka:9092
      ports:
        - "8080"
      depends_on:
        - kafka    

    ServiceB:
      image: elsoufy/myimage
      command: ./mycommand -role consumer -queue kafka:9092
      depends_on:
        - kafka     

networks:
      ...
```

`docker-compose up` will start services in dependency order. In the above example, `kafka` will be started before `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`.

**NOTE:** if you’re using `version 1` file format along with `links`, your app will work, but `Swarm` will schedule all containers on one host, because `links` between containers do not work across hosts with the old networking system.